# Is there a way to cache Python packages when building Vertex AI custom containers?

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, build, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am building a Vertex AI custom prediction contaier, but the deployment takes a very long time. [This](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/simplify-model-serving-custom-prediction-routines-vertex-ai) is the main article that I followed.
Each deploy takes around 30 minutes, and this is almost completely caused by installing Python packages. The packages don't change taht often, especially the big ones (which are Machine Learning related).

My deployment flow looks like this:

- First, I create a Docker image and install some dependencies.

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y my-depencency
```

- Then, I use this as my base image for the Vertex AI container.

```
from google.cloud.aiplatform.prediction import LocalModel

...

local_model = LocalModel.build_cpr_model(
    USER_SRC_DIR,
    IMAGE_NAME,
    predictor=MyPredictor,
    requirements_path=os.path.join(USER_SRC_DIR, "requirements.txt"),
    base_image=BASE_IMAGE_NAME,
)

local_model.push_image()
```

What I wanted to do is install the Python packages that are very big and not likely to change in the base image. This image would be built only once in a while, and the final image would take its packages from BASE.

However, I can't make this work because the packages are not automatically transfered to the second image. Normally, I would copy them, but I can't find a way to do this using the tools provided by the Google Cloud API.

The `build_cpr_model` parameters don't seem to give me that much flexibility. What I noticed is that you can specify custom packages, but I have no experience with these.

I am open to any way of reducing the deployment time.

Comment: Are you trying to copy (or use) libraries (my-dependency) from you base image inside of the custom-predictor container? if you already have the library in the base image where python environment can access, then the cpr image should be able to use them? trying to understand what you mean ` because the packages are not automatically transfered to the second image`? Another option you can try is to place your dependency (i.e .tar files) under the `src_dir` folder and pass it to the `build_cpr_model` call as a parameter. Vertex will copy all the content from this folder into the cpr image.

Comment: What I mean is that the second image doesn't have the Python packages from the first one. It keeps the things installed with `apt`, but everything else is just gone. When installing the Python dependencies, it reinstalls them like they were never there. Looking into the source code of `build_cpr_model`, I see that it adds this line to the Dockerfile to install the requirements: `RUN {} install --no-cache-dir {} -r {}`. So, I doubt that adding them to the `source dir` will change its behaviour.